# How to specify the year (in spreadsheet)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database

Not a native English speaker, and newbie in this forum. If anything is not clear, please let me know. Thanks

I have a data collection that has records of different cities in different years.

[image: data from 2013]
Data from 2013

[image: data from 2012]
Data from 2012

The district's total number will be the sum of the cities belonging to it.
The state's total number will be the sum of the districts belonging to it.

**My question is, how to specify that I only want to look at the data from year 2013.

And then from year 2010 and 2008 ...**

I only came up with a bad idea: add a new column and type the number of year in that range.
For example, from row 7 to row 532, I copy and paste "2013" in that column.
Like this:

[image: this].

Then fill 2012 from row 533 to row ..., until I finish all the years.

I feel like there's definitely a better way to specify year(s).
Any hints will be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: You may be looking for filters? Can you show us an example of what the end result should be?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the final result will be in the pivot table, and looks like this https://imgur.com/a/aDw2fex

Comment: Are you looking for the FILETER function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: That's some horrible data in column A. So if I correctly understand the problem, you have column A with a YEAR, followed by a bunch of data below it, then it switches to another year, and so on. I assume the number of rows is not consistent between years. So maybe 2013 has 525 rows, but 2012 might have 400 rows, and so on? Is there no other way to shape this data better prior to getting it into Excel?